# luatexluaescape string and backslash

Tags: luatex

I'm new to LuaLatex and I'm trying to write simple macros.

However, when I send a string to lua that contains a backslash (like `\R^n`), then the code doesn't work as expected.

For example, my lua code is:

```
function fourier(group, f)
    output = '\\mathcal{F}_{'..group..'}'
    if f ~= '' then
        output = output..'\\left\\{ {'..f..'} \\right\\}'
    end
    tex.sprint(output)
end
```

While the macro I'm trying to define is:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \F{D<>{}O{}}{%
    \directlua{
        fourier("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}", "\luatexluaescapestring{#2}")
    }
}
```

However, when I type `\[ \F<\R^n>[f] \]`, I get something on the pdf that looks like `\mathrm{F}_{@bgroup\R}^n {f}`.

Can someone help me?

EDIT: full code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{xparse}
\title{Title}
\author{bkn}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\directlua{dofile("functions.lua")}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \F{D<>{}O{}}{%
    \directlua{
        fourier("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}", "\luatexluaescapestring{#2}")
    }
}
\begin{document}

$\F<a>[f]$ % This works
$\F<\mathbb{R}^n>[f]$ % This doesn't

\end{document}
```

and functions.lua contains the above function.

Answer (score 3):

LuaTeX does `\edef`-like expansion inside `\directlua` (though the latter is itself expandable). To avoid this, you can use the e-TeX primitive `\unexpanded`

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \F{D<>{}O{}}{%
    \directlua{
        fourier(
         "\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}",
         "\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
         )
    }
}
```